# Accessing the value of a promise inside an Express Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-sheets-api

So basically I'm trying to get a list of sheets(e.g. Sheet 1, Sheet 2) from a single Google SpreadSheet and display that on my front-end.
I've got a Node.js server up and running and get data on the back-end from Google Sheets no problem.

What I want to do is send my array to my page as it renders. At the moment I'm able I'm getting the data in my console.log but my page won't render.

index.js // Server

```
const express = require('express');

const path = require('path');

const myGenerator = require('./app/myGenerator.js')

const app = express();


app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static('./app'));

app.get('/home', async (req, res, next) => {
  Promise.all([
    myGenerator.GetAllSheets()
  ]).then((value) => {
    res.render('home', { title: 'Hey', map1: value})
  })
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

myGenerator.js

```
module.exports = {
GetAllSheets: function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const googleSheetID = "REMOVED";

    // GOOGLE SHEETS CODE
    // Load client secrets from a local file.
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
      if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
      // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
      GoogleFunctions.authorize(JSON.parse(content), getData);
    });

    function getData(auth) {
      const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
      sheets.spreadsheets.get({
        spreadsheetId: `${googleSheetID}`
        }, (err, res) => {
          if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
          const rows = res.data.sheets;
          var map1 = rows.map(function(sheet) {
            return sheet.properties.title
          })
          console.log(map1);
          return map1;
      });
    }
  })
}
}
```

home.pug // view

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8') rel='stylesheet')
  body
    .container
      p The mysterious array should be here -> #{map1}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be very much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Well you never `resolve` or `reject` from your `GetAllSheets`..  IOW: `Promise((resolve, reject)` is doing absolutely nothing..

Comment: I'm an idiot, Keith you're a legend.
 Adding that in and everything works of course.
Should I delete this question or what? First question on SO

Comment: It's usually a good idea to keep for others..  I'll post an answer with fixes highlighted..

Comment: Nice response @Keith. @GeoFro `GetAllSheets` already returns a promise which resolves to your value so, why do you wrap it in `Promise.all([ ... ])`? That is not needed, there is only one promise so you can just do `myGenerator.GetAllSheets().then(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember when using `new Promise` to either `reject` or `resolve`, or you end up with a Promise that will never end.

Below is what the code should look like with fixes in place.

I've placed comments in the 3 places I changed.

Also it would be a good idea to `catch` error inside your routes, you could return a `500` error etc.

```
GetAllSheets: function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const googleSheetID = "REMOVED";
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
      //remember to also reject promise if error.
      if (err) return reject('Error loading client secret file:', err);
      GoogleFunctions.authorize(JSON.parse(content), getData);
    });

    function getData(auth) {
      const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
      sheets.spreadsheets.get({
        spreadsheetId: `${googleSheetID}`
        }, (err, res) => {
          //again if we have error, reject
          if (err) return reject('The API returned an error: ' + err);
          const rows = res.data.sheets;
          var map1 = rows.map(function(sheet) {
            return sheet.properties.title
          })
          //lets return our result
          return resolve(map1);
      });
    }
  })
}
```